# Search workbook for matching texts and replace value in all adjacent columns

Tags: excel, search, replace

Kinda newb in excel so I could appreciate your help.

So, right now I have a workbook with 49 sheets with different bank renovation quotations to give.

Some of the item descriptions are equal throughout the whole workbook and some are unique.

What I wanted was an excel formula that could let me chose a price for one item, lets say "wall construction" of 10,00$ and that would replicate for all the same description items in all the sheets.

Each item is in a separate line and the prices are 3 columns to the right of the item description (that would be the search term).

I think if there's a way to search for all cells with the same text and replace the cell 3 columns to the right that would do the job.

Unfortunately I've been playing with vlookup, index etc for a while but I need your help.

Comment: So there is one worksheet that has a unique master list of all of the items listed on all of the other 49 worksheets and you want to type in a new price for an item and have that price distributed to all 49 worksheets that contain that item. Is that an honest and accurate summary of what you want to do?

Comment: It can't be done with a formula. VBA is the tool you need. Can you accept that as an answer?

Comment: @Andreas - why can't this be done with a simple vlookup?

Comment: @user10852207 because vlookup only looks up values it can't replace values. There is no formula that can replace a value in another cell

Answer (score 0):

First create a "Master List" tab that will serve as your Quotebook with the service in column A and the price in column B.

Assuming your quote sheets are set up with a list of services needed in column A put the following formula in column B:

`=VLOOKUP(A1,Masterlist!A$2:B$90,2,False)`

**A1** = The cell with the service you need to price

**Masterlist!A$2:B$90** = The range of your Quotebook